# Increment variable names in loop

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to run a series of regressions in a for loop with different independent variables.

Example of independent variables which are created manually:

```
indep_vars_1 <- c("income", "female")
indep_vars_2 <- c("education", "wealth", "resources")
...
indep_vars_50 <- c("income", "size", "smoking", "pregnancy")
```

Combining all from 1 to 50:

```
indep_vars_all <- list(indep_vars_1, indep_vars_2 .... indep_vars_50)
```

Creating the loop:

```
for (i in indep_vars_all) {
  model_i <- pisa.reg.pv(pvlabel = "MATH", x = i, data = df)
}
```

The regressions are run using a package called `Intsvy` used to handle survey data with particular weights (no need to go into too much detail here on the package).

How can we end up with model_1 to model_50 using this loop please? I'm confused how to increment 'model'. I have tried `model_i` `model[i]` and other similar combinations without success.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the list and save the models. Try this:

```
#Vars
indep_vars_1 <- c("income", "female")
indep_vars_2 <- c("education", "wealth", "resources")
indep_vars_50 <- c("income", "size", "smoking", "pregnancy")
#Combine
indep_vars_all <- list(indep_vars_1, indep_vars_2 , indep_vars_50)
#create a list
List <- list()
#Loop
for (i in 1:length(indep_vars_all)) {
  List[[i]] <- pisa.reg.pv(pvlabel = "MATH", x = indep_vars_all[[i]], data = df)
}
#List of your models
names(List) <- paste0('model.',1:length(indep_vars_all))
List
list2env(List,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `lapply()` version as a substitute of `for` loop.

```
indep_vars_all <- setNames(indep_vars_all, paste0("indep_vars_", 1:50))
list2env(lapply(indep_vars_all, function(i){
  pisa.reg.pv(pvlabel = "MATH", x = i, data = df)
}), .GlobalEnv)
```

After executing the code above, `indep_vars_1` to `indep_vars_50` will be assigned into your workspace.